# Comparing variables of class Object

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a custom sorted binary tree in java, and I've had some problems with comparisons. I'm trying to implement a generic tree, so I would like to do something like:

```
public boolean contains(int i){
    if(i == currentNode.value) 
        return true;
    else if (i > currentNode.value) 
        // Go right
    else if (i < currentNode.value)
        // Go left
    ...
}
```

But I'm using objects (and I'm assuming they are objects that can be compared), so I wanted to do something like:

```
public boolean contains(Object o){
    if(o == currentNode.value) // value is of Object class
        return true;
    else if (o > currentNode.value) // Problem
        // Go right
    ...
}
```

So my problem right now is that it's not possible to use the operators > and < with objects, and so far I've been unable to think of another way to go about this.

Comment: You could use Comparable for the objects that support it, and use System.identityHashCode values to compare for objects that don't.  Of course, there's some (relatively slight) chance of collision with the hash codes, so you'd probably want to first compare class names, to "thin out" the hash space, then have a "punt" strategy if you still get a collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are not in inherently comparable, is an apple greater then an orange? Objects that are comparable implement the interface `Comparable`. So the simple answer is to replace every instance of `Object` in your binary tree with Comparable and have

```
int comparison = o.compareTo(currentNode.Value)
if(comparison ==0){
   ...
} else if (comparison > 0) {
   ...
} else  {
  // comparison < 0
   ...
}
```

You probably want to learn about java generics, which make your code much more type safe. 
You would start like this

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable> {
    public boolean contains(T target) {
       ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you could use it like

```
BinaryTree<Integer> tree = ...
tree.add(1);
tree.add(2);
tree.add("three"); // <-- Syntax error, compiler would fail.
...
Integer first = tree.getFirst();
Integer last = tree.getLast();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), then override the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method, for equality check. If you want to compare them, then implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, or create a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for them.

This answer won't explain in detail, how to use them, please read the docs (They are pretty detailed, and give you a good start, on the usage), or search for example usages, the internet is full of them.

Answer (score 1):

Objects that implement Comparable in java will have an method called compareTo that returns a integer. You just need to do your > and < tests on that, that is:

```
 int res = comparable.compareTo(other);
 if(res == 0){
   return true;
 } else if(res > 0){
   //go right
   ...
 } else {
   //go left
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what java comparable and generics are for!

Your objects should implement the: "int compareTo(Object obj)" method. If you were creating a binary search tree your contain method would look something like:

```
 public class MyTree<T extends Comparable<T>>{
 ...
    public boolean contains(TreeNode<T> node, T target)(
            if(node == null) return false;
            if(node.data.equals(target)){
                return true;
            }
            if(node.data.compareTo(target) > 0){//node is greater than target go left
                return contains(node.left, target);
            }else{
                return contains(node.right, target)//node is less than target go right
            }
    }
}
```